# Execute application from HTML in a USB

Tags: javascript, html, usb

I need this:

> The user inserts a USB drive in his PC. Then, it autoruns a .html
>   page in user's default browser. In the HTML page there are two
>   buttons: if the user presses button 1, I need to copy files to local
>   disk and then run these. If the user presses button 2, I need to call
>   a file from local disk.

I know how can autorun a .html file from USB memory. But 1) how can I copy files from HTML to local disk, and 2) how can I run files from local disk using HTML? (in Chrome, Firefox and IE).

Thanks!

Comment: You won't be able to do that via Javascript (thankfully). You'd need an executable at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

Purely from HTML you will not be able to execute **commands** on your computer.

In order to do that, you'd need to start a daemon on your computer that would answer HTTP requests from the browser and execute commands accordingly.

Or you'd need to have plugin for the browser that would do that, but I'm not sure whether plugins are able to escape the browser sandbox. Even if they could, the solution would be browser specific.